MediaStore contentResolver does not return anything when searching in EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
I'm working on an app and I'm trying to add functionality for searching (and playing) audio files. Right now I'm having an issue where the MediaStore contentResolver is not returning anything after querying.
fun search(query: String): MutableList<Track> {

        val outputTracks = mutableListOf<Track>()

        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,            // ID of the audio file
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,   // Name of the audio file
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH
            } else {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
            }
        )

        val selection = "(${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME} LIKE ? OR ${MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE} LIKE ?)"
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf("%${query}", "%${query}")

        try {
            context.contentResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null
            )?.use { cursor ->
                Log.i("FILETEST", "yaya2")
                if (cursor.count == 0) {
                    Log.i("FILETEST", "empty")
                } else {
                    Log.i("FILETEST", "not empty")
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    Log.i(
                        "FILETEST",
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME))
                    )

                    outputTracks.add(cursorToTrackClass(cursor))

                }
            }
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            Log.e("FILETEST", "Query failed: ", e)
        }

        return outputTracks

I added these in my AndroidManifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>

I tested on both a VD as on an actual phone; with no success.
On the VD I used the Device Explorer to add a .mp3 to both the Downloads folder as the Music folder.
I create a "SearchManager" in my onCreate() using: sm = SearchManager(applicationContext).
Using API 35 for my AVD. The query is not the issue; it does not work when passing null for both selection as selectionArgs either. I synchronized the files after uploading them. As you can guess, Logcat has never printed "not empty".
Edit: Using INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI instead does give me the results Deneb.ogg, Girtab.ogg and OrganDub.ogg (sample sounds put into my project by Android Studio I assume). But still no result using EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
Edit2:
Permissions are requested at run-time and when I go to the settings on the VD it says permission granted. Code used:
val requestPermissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission())
            { isGranted: Boolean ->
                if (!isGranted) {
                    // Permission not granted, show snackbar that says that app is unusable
                    // and/or close app
                    // NotifyNoPermissionSnackbar()
                }
            }
        // Check android version to support both older as newer android versions
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            // Ask permission if not granted, else do nothing
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // If permission not already granted, ask for permission
                    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO)
            }
        }
        else {
            // Ask permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE instead, for older android versions
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Ask permission if not granted, else do nothing
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // If permission not already granted, ask for permission
                    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                }
            }
        }```

Edit3: title


It's not enough to add the permissions to the manifest file. You have to request them at runtime. See: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Sorry, I did not add in my original post but I do request them during run-time. Edited my post with code I used for this.

Fixed it:
val selectionArgs = arrayOf("%${query}", "%${query}")
should have % behind as well:
val selectionArgs = arrayOf("%${query}%", "%${query}%")
